# How can I count repeated columns?

Tags: mysql

I did 3 tables the problem is that I'm trying to count how many times are plate values in my table and compare it with and specific policy.

**TABLES**

```
|vehicles|             
  |id|  |plate|          
    1   VEH001
    2   VEH002
    3   VEH003
    4   VEH004
    5   VEH001
    6   VEH002

|policy_vehicles|
  |id|  |vehicle_id| |policy_id|
   1         1            1
   2         2            1
   3         3            1
   4         4            2
   5         6            3

|policies|
  |id|  |description|
   1     POL1
   2     POL2
   3     POL3
```

I want to count when plate name is repeated on the "DATABASE" in this case "VEH001" is repeated 1 time on the table vehicles from policy_id = 1.

**For example policy_id = 1**

```
Policy: POL1 
Has 3 policy_vehicles  
Has 3 plates ( VEH001, VEH002, VEH003)
VEH001 and VEH002 are repeated in the DB = 2 plates repeated
```

I'm trying to show this as result

```
REPEATED
  2
```

Another example count when plate name is not repeated on the "DATABASE" in this case "VEH004" is not repeated on the table vehicles from policy_id =2

**For example policy_id = 2**

```
Policy: POL2 
Has 1 policy_vehicles  
Has 1 plates ( VEH002 )
VEH002 is repeated in the DB = 1 plate repeated
```

I'm trying to show this as result

```
REPEATED
  0
```

Another example count when plate name is repeated on the "DATABASE" in this case "VEH002" is repeated on the table vehicles from policy_id =3

**For example policy_id = 3**

```
Policy: POL3 
Has 1 policy_vehicles  
Has 1 plates ( VEH004 )
VEH004 is not repeated
```

I'm trying to show this as result

```
REPEATED
  1
```

I tried [this live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e71b/2)

```
Select count(*) FROM (
  SELECT count(*), v.plate
  FROM vehicles v
  LEFT JOIN policy_vehicles pv ON v.id = pv.vehicle_id
  and pv.policy_id = 2
 GROUP by v.plate 
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) A
```

Please somebody can help me with this?

Comment: Your expected results don't make sense. Vehicles 1 and 4 don't belong to the same policy, and vehicle 5 doesn't belong to any. I'm not sure how you can say they are repeated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said, " want to count all plates repetead from an specific policy", and "I want to count when plate name is repeated on the "DATABASE" in this case "VEH001" and "VEH002" are repeated 2 times on the table vehicles."

having I believe will give you what your after.  It's a limit imposed AFTER the counts are done.  Where clause is applied BEFORE the counts are done.

```
SELECT count(*), v.plate
FROM vehicles v
LEFT JOIN policy_vehicles pv ON v.id = pv.vehicle_id
and pv.policy_id = 1
GROUP by v.plate 
HAVING count(*) > 1 ;
```

Would return all plates and their respective duplicate counts.
Now it sounds like you want a count of that soo...

```
Select count(*) FROM (
   SELECT count(*), v.plate
FROM vehicles v
LEFT JOIN policy_vehicles pv ON v.id = pv.vehicle_id
and pv.policy_id = 1
GROUP by v.plate 
HAVING count(*) > 1 ) A
```

Comment: XQbert...I did what you explained and got nothing http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/042d6/12  please read my question again I edited what I really want.

Comment: It's becuase those plates are not on that policy.  I reread and yes I missed that part.  If you want a count irrespective of being on that policy... make it a left join and move the where clause to the join we can get all the plates.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/042d6/16/1  The inner join is eliminating (some) the plates you want to count and a where clause on policy vehicle is eliminating the rest.  So we make an outer join and move the where clause to the join itself to prevent it eliminating nulls created by the join.  Fiddle helped immensely :P

Comment: xQbert ...I was testing your query but is not working when using policy_id = 2 ...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e71b/2 and should get 0

Comment: I did for last time using 3 examples about the question, I'll thank you if you can help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you help me please? xQbert I will really thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by getting all of the rows in question, before preforming any aggregation. You can do so with inner joins like this:

```
SELECT p.description, pv.vehicle_id, v.plate
FROM policies p
JOIN policy_vehicles pv ON pv.policy_id = p.id
JOIN vehicles v ON v.id = pv.vehicle_id
WHERE p.id = 1;
```

To see how many times each vehicle plate is repeated, I wrote one subquery that gets a count for each plate like this:

```
SELECT v.plate, COUNT(*) AS repeated
FROM vehicles v
GROUP BY v.plate;
```

Then, I joined the two together to see each repeat value:

```
SELECT t1.description, t1.vehicle_id, t1.plate, t2.repeated
FROM(
  SELECT p.description, pv.vehicle_id, v.plate
  FROM policies p
  JOIN policy_vehicles pv ON pv.policy_id = p.id
  JOIN vehicles v ON v.id = pv.vehicle_id
  WHERE p.id = 1) t1
JOIN(
  SELECT v.plate, COUNT(*) AS repeated
  FROM vehicles v
  GROUP BY v.plate) t2 ON t2.plate = t1.plate;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/042d6/20) example.